# Does this explanation of Left Joins make sense?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the query I'm trying to visually represent and diagrams and small explanation I made.
I realize it would be much easier not using Venn Diagrams for joins but I don't understand it enough to use anything else like Cartesian products.
I just want to make sure it makes sense because I'm having a hard time understanding the joining of 3 or more tables.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The diagram is incorrect. It is difficult to fit everything into a single drawing. Try to think of the joins in sequence. You know how the first join looks like (`A left join AL`). You could think of the result of the first join as a new table (call it `TMP`). Then add another drawing for the 3rd join (`TMP left join B`).

Comment: Thanks doing that will make this a lot easier!

Answer (score 3):

You would want something like this:

[image]

- You will have the entirety of the blue (author) area.
- You will have the red (Allocation) area that overlaps the blue (Author) area and for the rest of the blue area that does not overlap the red area then the Allocation column values will be `NULL`.
- You will have the green (Book) area that overlaps the intersection of the red (Allocation) and blue (Author) area (where all 3 colours overlap) and for the rest of the blue area that does not overlap the green area then the Book column values will be `NULL`.
- The areas of the red (Allocation) and green (Book) circles that do not overlap the blue (Author) circle will be excluded from the result set.

Comment: This is a good diagram.  I might suggest that the first bullet not be bulleted, because it is what is returned.  The other bullet points refine the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For a 3 table left join:

```
1.For table Author, it looks at every entry and checks if it exists in
    table Allocation. If it does not, it returns null.

2. For those entries which were not null in the previous join, checks
    if they exist in table Book. If it does not, it returns null.
```

Hope this helps. I agree that the diagram might not be the best representation for 3 or more tables joined.